# Call service method from a property

Tags: ember.js, methods, service, properties

I am getting an error in the console saying the service is not defined when attempting to call a service method inside a property on my controller.

```
itemImage: function(){
    return this.get('s3').getItemImage(this.get('user.active_auction'),this.get('model.item_image'));
}.property(),
```

The error states

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: s3 is not defined
```

The method should go out to s3, get an item.

```
getItemImage(auction_id, image) {
    var self = this;
    s3.getObject({Bucket: self.get('bucketName'),Key: auction_id+'/'+image},function(err,data){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
   })
}
```

What must I do to get this to work?

Comment: Is s3 defined inside getItemImage?

Comment: Ah yeah it was but I wasn't getting it properly, I just assumed it was the controller yelling at me but it was indeed the service method.

Answer (score 2):

If `s3` is indeed a service. You need to inject it into your controller.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { inject, computed } = Ember;
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  s3: inject.service(),
  itemImage: computed(function(){
    return this.get('s3').getItemImage(this.get('user.active_auction'),this.get('model.item_image'));
}.property(),  
});
```

Now, If I understand what you're trying to do... That `s3` service seems to be making some call that returns a promise. As far as I know you it's not a good policy to have computed properties return a promise. [Reference](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2015/06/10/cps-promise/)

Now I think you can do something like this (if what you need can be started by an action or something (example bellow for an action named `someAction`):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { inject, computed } = Ember;
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  s3: inject.service(),
  image: null,
  itemImage: computed('image', function() {
    return this.get('image');
  }),

  actions: {
    someAction() {
        let self = this;
        this.get('s3').getObject({Bucket: self.get('bucketName'),Key: auction_id+'/'+image},function(err,data){
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
          self.set('image', data);
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

This way, when the `s3` service resolves the object it sets the `image` property to the value returned by the s3 object. Since the `itemImage` property is dependent on the `image` property, whenever the `image` is updated by the s3 object it will also update the computed property which you can use in your templates.

Hope I've helped. Not 100% sure if I understood what you wanted to do.

Comment: I like this approach, the catch here WAS that I needed the image to be fetched on template render. I was transitioning from an `items` route to an `item` route and wanted the image for that `item` to be loaded when the template loads. I suppose I could use some `didTransition` hook but it turns out I don't need to do this since S3 assets can be loaded by just specifiing their endpoint directly in a `src` attribute. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad I could "help", best of luck with your ember app!